# Show $g(n)$ takes a finite value for every $n$ for the function $g(n) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \sin (nx) \, dx$ where $n \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Show $g(n)$ takes a finite value for every $n$ for the function $g(n) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \sin (nx) \, dx$ where $n \in \mathbb{R}$.

Well, $-1 \le \sin(nx) \le 1$.  So if we can prove $f(x)$ is finite then the product of $\sin(nx)$ and $f(x)$ is finite.  Would that then make $g(x)$ finite?  If so, then how would I go about showing an arbitrary function is finite for each element of its domain?

Could we approximate $g(x)$ by using a function that is dense in $L^1 (\mathbb{R})$ and show that this approximate function is finite for each element in its domain?  i.e.  approximate f(x) with a simple function, step function, or a continuous function with compact support.

Really stuck here any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to assume something about $f$. For example, this certainly does not hold for $f(x) = x^2$ or $f(x) = \sin(x)$.

Comment: @User8128 Well, I do know that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \sin (nx) \, dx = 0$.  I believe that was a theorem.  Therefore f(x) certainly couldn't be sin(x) and couldn't be x^2 as well.  Ahh so f(x) would have to be finite then...correct?

Comment: What you're referring to is the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma; it holds for $f \in L^1(\mathbb R)$. That is the requirement you need in order to $g$ to be finite for all $n$, you need $f \in L^1(\mathbb R)$.